# Windows OpenVpn: client doesn't see another machines in network

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have configured OpenVPN server on windows server 2008 and client on windows 7. Connection between them is ok, there is a server default gateway in route table (192.168.0.1) but i can't see another machines in network and field with gateway address for TAP-Windows Adapter V9 is empty. I've added push "redirect-gateway def1" on server and push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" on client, firewall is off... Please help me, because I'm a new OpenVPN user and I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem, but still nothing:(

### server.ovpn

```
mode server

local 192.168.0.197

port 1194

proto udp

dev tap0

persist-key

persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"

cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\albaserver.crt"

key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\albaserver.key"

dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh1024.pem"

tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 0

cipher BF-CBC

comp-lzo

server-bridge 192.168.0.197 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.171 192.168.0.180

push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1" 

push "redirect-gateway def1"

max-clients 10

user nobody

group nogroup

keepalive 10 120

status openvpn-status.log
```

### client.ovpn

```
client

dev tap0

proto udp

remote my_remote_server_address 1194

nobind

resolv-retry infinite

persist-key

persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"

cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\albaclient2.crt"

key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\albaclient2.key" 

tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

cipher BF-CBC

comp-lzo
```

### server log

```
Mon Jul 22 13:34:46 2013 NOTE: --user option is not implemented on Windows

Mon Jul 22 13:34:46 2013 NOTE: --group option is not implemented on Windows

Mon Jul 22 13:34:46 2013 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] 
[eurephia] [IPv6] built on Jun  3 2013
Mon Jul 22 13:34:46 2013 NOTE: when bridging your LAN adapter with the TAP adapter, note 
that the new bridge adapter will often take on its own IP address that is different from what the LAN adapter was previously set to

Mon Jul 22 13:34:46 2013 NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 
192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet cafes that use the same 
subnet.
Mon Jul 22 13:34:47 2013 Control Channel Authentication: using 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN
\config\ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Mon Jul 22 13:34:47 2013 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0

Mon Jul 22 13:34:47 2013 TAP-WIN32 device [Po?czenie lokalne 3] opened: \\.\Global
\{4E9F5624-F9C6-47F8-BA83-FF44BD7E8F62}.tap
Mon Jul 22 13:34:47 2013 Sleeping for 10 seconds...

Mon Jul 22 13:34:57 2013 Successful ARP Flush on interface [25] {4E9F5624-F9C6-47F8-
BA83-FF44BD7E8F62}
Mon Jul 22 13:34:57 2013 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]192.168.0.197:1194

Mon Jul 22 13:34:57 2013 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]

Mon Jul 22 13:34:57 2013 Initialization Sequence Completed

Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 ADDRESS:64329 [albaclient2] Peer Connection Initiated with 
[AF_INET]ADDRESS:64329
Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 albaclient2/ADDRESS:64329 MULTI_sva: pool returned 
IPv4=192.168.0.171, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Mon Jul 22 13:35:28 2013 albaclient2/ADDRESS:64329 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
```

### client log

```
Mon Jul 22 13:35:15 2013 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [IPv6] built on Jun  3 2013

Mon Jul 22 13:35:15 2013 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.

Mon Jul 22 13:35:16 2013 Control Channel Authentication: using 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file

Mon Jul 22 13:35:16 2013 UDPv4 link local: [undef]

Mon Jul 22 13:35:16 2013 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]MY REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS:1194

Mon Jul 22 13:35:22 2013 [albaserver] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]MY REMOTE 
SERVER ADDRESS:1194
Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0

Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0

Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 TAP-WIN32 device [Po?czenie lokalne 2] opened: \\.\Global
\{D5B721DA-C466-472E-846B-A1915686F314}.tap
Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 
192.168.0.171/255.255.255.0 on interface {D5B721DA-C466-472E-846B-A1915686F314} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.0.0, lease-time: 31536000]

Mon Jul 22 13:35:25 2013 Successful ARP Flush on interface [45] {D5B721DA-C466-472E-
846B-A1915686F314}
Mon Jul 22 13:35:30 2013 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

### ipconfig

[image: [IMG]http://imageshack.us/a/img694/6686/cmq5.png[/IMG]]

### route -n

[image: [IMG]http://imageshack.us/a/img843/6918/a8ml.png[/IMG]]

Comment: "your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 
192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet cafes that use the same 
subnet."  - is your Win7 client's lan *BEFORE* you connect a 192.168.0.x/24 network?  If it is, you'll conflict.  It is best to have your work network (even a VPN subnet) on something besides 192.168.x.x if possible.

Comment: I've changed line server-bridge 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.10 192.168.20.20 and it's still the same problem:( I'm not able to change local network addresses, because it's a company network and everything works on it:/

Comment: on your route list all I see is a default and the local connection having the lower metric.  I don't know OpenVPN so I can't comment with 100% surety, but it would seem that either you need your VPN to have the lower metric or you need explicit routes to the 192.168.0.x company network in your VPN config to force the traffic that direction.